# Flutter Passing Document ID in Firestore Query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out how to do this.

If I pass the document ID hardcoded it works. But Since I have multiple pages, I am trying to figure out how to pass it and then query it..

My main page has the following.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onlytag2/pages/category.dart';
import 'package:onlytag2/widget/maincard.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;

  List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot;

  Query collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("mainCategories").orderBy("title");

  void initState() {
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        snapshot = datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel(); //Streams must be closed when not needed
    super.dispose();
  }

  passData(DocumentSnapshot snap, String cat, String title) {
    print(cat);
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Category(snapshot: snap, category: cat, title: title,)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (snapshot == null) return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 300.0,
              maxWidth: 200.0,
              minWidth: 150.0,
              minHeight: 150.0
          ),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff0E0E0F),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "#",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25, color: Color(0xffff9900), fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
            ),
            Text(
              "onlytags",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () => passData(snapshot[index], snapshot[index].documentID.toString(), snapshot[index].data["title"] ),
                          child: MainCard(
                            title: snapshot[index].data["title"],
                            subtitle: snapshot[index].data["subTitle"],
                            image: snapshot[index].data["image"],
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The category widget is where I am having the problem.

Comment Listed where I am having the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onlytag2/widget/sub.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Category extends StatefulWidget {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
  final String category;
  final String title;

  Category({this.snapshot, this.category, this.title});

  @override
  _CategoryState createState() => _CategoryState();
}

class _CategoryState extends State<Category>{
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;

  List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot;

  //How do I get the category passed properly? I know it is the Document ID, but since it changes based on what button is pressed before,
  //I cant figure out how to pass it..
  Query collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("mainCategories").document(widget.category).collection("subCategories").orderBy("title");

  void initState() {
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        snapshot = datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel(); //Streams must be closed when not needed
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (snapshot == null) return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 300.0,
              maxWidth: 200.0,
              minWidth: 150.0,
              minHeight: 150.0
          ),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff0E0E0F),
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Color(0xffff9900),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "#", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color(0xffff9900), fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
            ),
            Text(widget.title.toLowerCase(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Sub(
                          title: snapshot[index].data["title"],
                          subtitle: snapshot[index].data["subTitle"],
                          image: snapshot[index].data["image"],
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```I am trying to figure out how to pass it and then query it```. I think in the code above, the document ID  gets passed to ```_CategoryState```, what was intended?

Comment: So right now I have Sub categories. I need the list builder to build out those subCategories for that document ID.

Comment: widget.category does not work. it gives me an error

Comment: What error specifically does it throw?

Comment: widget.category in the query throws the error only static members can be accessed in intializers

Comment: Ah i see why, can you adjust your code like this to see if it will work, ```Query collectionReference;

  void initState() { collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("mainCategories").document(widget.category).collection("subCategories").orderBy("title");
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        snapshot = datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have realised that the code looks shady on the comment so let me make an answer.
What you are trying to do is currently not supported in flutter as can be seen at these GitHub issues [1](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/15346) and [2](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26210).

Change your code to,

```dart
class _CategoryState extends State<Category>{
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;

  List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot;

  Query collectionReference;

  void initState() {
    collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("mainCategories").document(widget.category).collection("subCategories").orderBy("title");
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        snapshot = datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! simple enough fix.